# How to pass UserName & Password in IBMMQ Client Message using .NET or C++ Program

Tags: authentication, c#-4.0, ibm-mq

I am writing a .NET Console application, our goal is keep a message on the queue and read the message.  the message header should contain User Name  & Password.  I try to pass the Message with below code it is not working.

```
        hashTable.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT);
        hashTable.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, strServerName);
        hashTable.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, strChannelName);
        hashTable.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, 1414);             
        hashTable.Add(MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, "XXXXXX");
        hashTable.Add(MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "XXXXXX");
        hashTable.Add(MQC.USE_MQCSP_AUTHENTICATION_PROPERTY, true);      
        queueManager = new MQQueueManager(strQueueManagerName,hashTable);         
        queue = queueManager.AccessQueue(requestQueue, MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
        requestMessage = new MQMessage();          
  
        requestMessage.WriteString(StrAPICMessage);
        requestMessage.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
        requestMessage.MessageType = MQC.MQMT_REQUEST;
        requestMessage.Report = MQC.MQRO_COPY_MSG_ID_TO_CORREL_ID;
        requestMessage.ReplyToQueueName = responseQueue;
        requestMessage.ReplyToQueueManagerName = strQueueManagerName;
        queuePutMessageOptions = new MQPutMessageOptions();
        queue.Put(requestMessage, queuePutMessageOptions);
```

In the Message Descriptor it is taking the default value mentioned MQ Server.  it is not takeing my UserName "XXXXX"

I have tried using the CSICS Bridge header also unable to send the message with my application Service account  + Password.
help me on this scenario.

Comment: What version of dll from IBM are you using?

Comment: What do the client and server side error logs show?

Answer (score 1):

See "MQCSP authentication mode" here:  https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/latest?topic=authentication-connection-java-client

It says:

*In this mode, the client-side user ID is sent as well as the user ID and password to be authenticated, so you are able to use ADOPTCTX(NO). The user ID and password are available to a server-connection security exit in the MQCSP structure that is provided in the MQCXP structure.*

"client-side user ID" means the UserId that the application is running under.  Therefore, if you are authenticating with a different UserId than the one that the application is running under.

Therefore, you (or your MQAdmin) will need to change ADOPTCTX to YES.

Comment: Hi Roger,  Thank you for giving the inputs.  in our Queue Manager we already set ADOPTCTX as Yes.
  and passing the code as mentioned above.  Do i need to make any change.

Comment: Its time to run an MQ trace on the client-side to see what is going on.

Comment: How can we enable the MQ Trace  on Client Side.

Comment: we already enabled the Trace, but it is not getting logged anything,

Comment: The UserIds that are sent across the wire will be in the trace.  Otheriwise, open a ticket with IBM and get them to investigate.

Comment: We have opened the P3 Ticket with IBM Team, They said we will not support coding and others.  I know you have written so many code for MQ, can you give a sample code for sending UserID and password with C# or C++

Answer (score 0):

Your program works fine for me, when I fill in the correct values for my qmgr connection.

Except for one change I made: instead of `TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT` I used `TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED`. That keeps everything in the managed .Net space.

Without that change, I was actually getting MQRC_UNSUPPORTED_FUNCTION during the connection which typically means either some kind of mismatch between versions of interfaces, or it couldn't find the C dll that underpins the unmanaged environment. And I wasn't going to take time to dig into that further.

Running `amqsbcg` against the output queue, I see

```
 UserIdentifier : 'mqguest     '
```

which is the id I had set in the `USER_ID_PROPERTY`.

Comment: Thank you, Mark for your Valuable Time, helping me on this Question.
As you recommended, I changed the property and Tried I see the 
Queue Manager --> Channels --> Chanel Authentication Records --> Channel Profile --> Extended --> MCA User ID.
I am not getting what I have kept in a Hashtable